# Seeking collaborative map editor tool for non-technical users with OpenStreetMap basemap

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping, software-recommendations, crowdsourcing

I'm looking for a tool to allow non-technical users to create map polygons based off printed maps, and export them into a geographiclal format.

It should be based on OSM base tiles (to avoid licensing issues) and ideally offer open satellite imagery too.

The basic requirements are: easy to sign up for, easy to use, and allow data export in an open format.

I have found [UMap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/), which basically does what I need, but I would ideally like something with satellite tiles (a lot of my data is in the countryside, where OSM is less detailed, and it would be useful to check underlying geographical features).

I don't mind asking my users to install a piece of software, so I could use desktop software if that's easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At [Mango](https://mangomap.com) we will shortly (within the next few weeks) be releasing a teams feature that will allow for multiple users on a single account and group editing. It offers OSM base maps and satellite base maps.